# I CAN'T ping PC7

Tags: spanning-tree, ping, packet-tracer

[image]

So... I have a set up as below. I ping PC7 from the router. obviously an ARP is sent to determine PC7's MAC address. but it doesnt work. i then decide to set packettracer to simulation mode. i ping pc7 again and then. i notice that the switch drops the arp for some reason. I dont get why. someone out there in the world should know why.

[image]

notice how it says gigabit ethernet is blocked by STP. It seems i lack in understanding of STP. some wiser being please save me.

since i think its an issue on the switch. here is its running-config

!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 32
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 64
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 96
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,32,64,96
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!

Comment: You need to post the full configurations in order for us to help.

Comment: i'm on it......

Comment: i had configured all the ports with spanning-tree portfast command i thought that was the problem so i negated the command @JFL

Comment: How is the router configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeeei. I'm so thrilled i found my mistake. I didn't makeg that port on the switch to the router a trunking port... i'm so sorry i didn't tell you guys about all the VLANS i had in there... i see how there was no way you could have seen that. anyways:

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,32,64,96
 spanning-tree portfast
!
```

this plase should have been:

```
! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
   switchport mode trunk
   switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,32,64,96 
   spanning-tree portfast 
!
```

Thank you guys for trying to help me here. it  would have depressed me to death. you saved my life

Comment: That is why you need to give us the _full_ configurations of the network devices when asking such question.

Comment: Also, please accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wait for the port to goes in forwarding mode.

By default on Cisco switches (and it seems in packet tracer), when a port goes UP, the STP process block the port until it determines that the network is loop-free, by listening for BPDU on this port.

To avoid this you can configure ports that are connected to hosts (I.E. not  other switches) with the `spanning-tree portfast`command.
This will cause the port to goes in forwarding mode immediately upon connection, but still run STP discovery and block the port if a loop is detected.

Comment: i had configured all the ports with spanning-tree portfast command i thought that was the problem so i negated the command

Comment: Sooo.... thats not the issue here.... but you could still help me figure this out. its killing me

Comment: @Frankline Ok but did you wait long enough for the port to transition in the forwarding state?